# Play Framework: getting foursquare access token

Tags: web-services, playframework-2.0, foursquare

I am trying to grasp how Play framework handles its web service calls.

This is Foursquare's directions (after 1 and 2):

```
Your server will make a request for
https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token
    ?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
    &client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
    &grant_type=authorization_code
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
    &code=CODE

The response will be JSON
{ access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN }
```

And this is my code:

```
public static Result index() {
    String base = "http://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate";
    String clientId = "?client_id=***";
    String responseType = "&response_type=code";
    String redirectUri = "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/code";
    return redirect(base + clientId + responseType + redirectUri);
}


public static Result code() {
        String base = "http://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token";
        String clientId = "?client_id=***";
        String clientsecret = "&client_secret=***";
        String grantType = "&grant_type=authorization_code";
        String redirectUri = "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/json";
        String code = "&code=" + request().getQueryString("code");

        return redirect(base + clientId + clientsecret + grantType
                + redirectUri + code);

    }
```

There are two things I am curios about:

1) I am redirected to a page with the access token displayed on screen:

URL: `https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=***&client_secret=***&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/json&code=***`

With this displayed:

```
{"access_token":"***"}
```

I would have expected to be redirected to `http://localhost:9000/json` as that was the redirect uri...

2) How do I grab the access token? I have tried using the asynchronous web service calls vis http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaWS but I cannot make them work.

My attempt:

```
String feedUrl = base + clientId + clientsecret + grantType
                + redirectUri + code;

        final Promise<Result> resultPromise = WS.url(feedUrl).get().map(
                new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                    public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                        return ok("Feed title:" + response.asJson().findPath("access_token").asText());
                    }
                }
        );

        return resultPromise;
```

This gives me an exception: `[ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: foursquare.com/107.23.103.139:80 to http://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token]`

All help is appreciated greatly!

Comment: Query parameters to a WS call are set using .withQueryString("key1" -> "value1"), not by merging them to the url by hand!

Comment: This was quick and dirty. I am using java so I cannot use your syntax. The main problem was getting the WS call to work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't think about the language differences. With the Java api it looks like this: WS.url("http://example.com").setQueryParameter("key1", "value1") which returns a RequestHolder so you can chain the calls without having to store each step as a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is the class that I made to get the foursquare access_token and submit a new search to foursquare:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    static final String HOST_AUTHENTICATE = "foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate";
    static final String HOST_ACCESS_TOKEN = "https://www.foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token";
    static final String CLIENT_ID = "***";
    static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:9000/code";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "***";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE = "authorization_code";
    static final String RESPONSE_TYPE = "code";
    static final String FOURSQUARE_API_FRIENDS = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/friends";

    public static Result index() {
        String uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https").setHost(HOST_AUTHENTICATE)
                .setParameter("client_id", CLIENT_ID).setParameter("response_type", RESPONSE_TYPE)
                .setParameter("redirect_uri", REDIRECT_URI).toString();

        return redirect(uri);
    }

    public static Promise<Result> code() {
        WSRequestHolder authenticate = WS.url(HOST_ACCESS_TOKEN).setQueryParameter("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
                .setQueryParameter("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET).setQueryParameter("grant_type", GRANT_TYPE)
                .setQueryParameter("redirect_uri", REDIRECT_URI)
                .setQueryParameter("code", request().getQueryString("code").toString());

        final Promise<Result> resultPromise = authenticate.get().flatMap(new Function<WS.Response, Promise<Result>>() {
            public Promise<Result> apply(WS.Response response) {
                JsonNode json = response.asJson();
                return WS.url(FOURSQUARE_API_FRIENDS).setQueryParameter("oauth_token", json.findPath("access_token").asText())
                        .setQueryParameter("v", "20131108").get().map(new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
                            public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                                return ok(response.asJson());
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        return resultPromise;
    }

}
```